# Applying methods conditionally across columns in a pivot table

Tags: python, python-polars

Really enjoying chaining in polars. Almost feels like dplyr in R. Question: Is there a way to apply `fill_null` conditionally across columns in the table (i.e., replace with 0 for numerics and "0%" for str in the example below)? Like the old `mutate_if` in R-dplyr.

```py
import polars as pl

scores = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "zone": ["North", "North", "North", "South", "South", "East", "East", "East", "East"],
        "funding": ["yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes"],
        "score": [78, 39, 76, 56, 67, 89, 100, 55, 80],
    }
)

(
    scores.groupby(["zone", "funding"])
    .agg(pl.count().alias("count"))
    .with_columns(
        [
            pl.col("count").over("funding"),
            pl.format(
                "{}%",
                (pl.col("count") * 100 / pl.sum("count"))
                .over("funding")
                .round(2),
            ).alias("perc"),
        ]
    )
    .pivot(["count", "perc"], "zone", "funding")
    .with_columns(
        [
            pl.col("count_yes").fill_null(0),
            pl.col("perc_yes").fill_null("0%")
        ]
    )
)
```

EDIT: Based on @jquiros' excellent suggestions the below works if you want to explicitly column types to apply the `is_null` method to columns of different types

```py
(
    scores.groupby(["zone", "funding"])
    .agg(pl.count().alias("count"))
    .with_columns(
        [
            pl.col("count").over("funding"),
            pl.format(
                "{}%",
                (pl.col("count") * 100 / pl.sum("count"))
                .over("funding")
                .round(2),
            ).alias("perc"),
        ]
    )
    .pivot(["count", "perc"], "zone", "funding")
    .with_columns(
        [
            pl.col("*").exclude(pl.Utf8).fill_null(0),
            pl.col(pl.Utf8).fill_null("0%")
        ]
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean without naming columns e.g. `.pivot().fill_null(0).fill_null("0%")`?

Comment: That works nicely @jqurious for this example. Thanks. I was trying to understand how to use something conditional, perhaps with `when`, `then`, `otherwise` that would check if a column is of a specific type and then apply the desired `fill_null` as needed for all columns in a df. Not needed here but I'd be very interested in seeing the mechanics how something like that works in polars (ala `across` in dplyr https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)

Comment: When you `.fill_null()` polars will match value given against the column types for you. You can [explicitly select columns by type](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.col.html#polars-col)  e.g. `pl.col(pl.Uint32).fill_null(0), pl.col(pl.Utf8).fill_null("0%")`